# Retrying connection Paramiko - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

Wrote a function that tries to reconnect to SSH when a disconnect happens. Basically expanded my existing function that simply saved the images, which works fine. The code runs but does not work to re-establish connectivity. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def get_image_id_and_upload_folder_of_images(db_name, table_name, selector_list,
                                         condition_label, condition_val, img_address):
"""
get image id using project name from db
:param db_name: str - name of the data-base (usually 'server')
:param table_name: str - name of the table (usually 'images')
:param selector_list: list of str - list of selectors for the query (usually ["id", "path"])
:param condition_label: str - condition for the sql statement (like 'path')
:param condition_val: list of str - value for the condition of the condition_label (like ['name_of_file.png'])
:param img_address:  str - address of the images to send them to the ftp server
:return: returns image or project id
"""
client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
retry_interval = 1
retry_interval = float(retry_interval)
timeout = int(20)
timeout_start = time.time()
while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
    time.sleep(retry_interval)
    try:
        db, cur = db_info(db_name)
        cond_list = ["'" + str(x) + "'" for x in condition_val]
        condition = ",".join(cond_list)
        selector = ",".join(selector_list)
        # make a query for sql
        query_stmt = "SELECT " + selector + " FROM " + table_name + " WHERE `" + \
                     condition_label + "` IN (" + str(condition) + ");"

        image_ids = get_image_ids(cur, db, query_stmt, condition_val)
        for idx, ids in enumerate(image_ids):
            print(ids)
            save_img_new_server(img_address + '/' + condition_val[idx], str(ids))
            save_img_new_server(img_address + '/' + condition_val[idx], str(ids), hst="site.com",
                                folder_path='images/')
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError as e:
        print('SSH transport is not ready...')
        continue

    # print(img_address + '/' + condition_val[idx], str(ids))

return image_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code never calls `client.connect()`. In fact it doesn't interact with any paramiko module at all inside the while loop.